# Как включить бота в группе. Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

как бота подключить к чату? В личных сообщениях с ботом работает отлично, но ни на одну команду в чате/группе не отвечает, все настройки приватности в BotFather включены на то, чтобы он все в чате видел, но это не помогло, что нужно добавить в код, чтобы это работало? Может событие?

Comment: для доступа к сообщениям группы/канала бот должен быть администратором. а так же непонятно какие команды у вас запрограммированы, поэтому сложно сказать в коде проблема или нет.